# passing column value as parameter in sql

Tags: sql

Say I have a table `customerDemand` with two columns: `customer_id`, `demand`

Now I have a function `fnMapCustToBucket` which takes a `customer_id` and maps it to a test bucket

I want to write a query that that returns me a table of: `bucket`, `customer_id`, `demand`.

I'm trying:

```
select
    customer_id id,
    demand d,
    db.fnMapCustToBucket(id) 
from
    customerDemand
```

This doesn't work because `id` at the point of the function call seems to be undefined. Help would be much appreciated here. Thanks!

Comment: Use `customer_id` instead of `id`. And correct tags.

Comment: It should work dbo.fnMapCustToBucket(customer_id)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select customer_id id, demand d,
db.fnMapCustToBucket(customer_id)
from customerDemand
```